# response.getState() is coming as error in helper

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am trying to complete Apex Framework specialist. Challenge 3.

I have the following method in class

```
    public class BoatSearchResults {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Boat__c> getBoats(String boatTypeId){

        List<Boat__c> boatList= null;

        if(boatTypeId != null && boatTypeId!= ''){
            try{
                boatList = [select BoatType__c, Contact__c, Description__c, Geolocation__c, Length__c, Picture__c, Price__c, Year_Built__c from Boat__c where BoatType__c =: boatTypeId];
            }

            catch(Exception e){
                System.debug('Error' +e);
            }
        }
        else{
            try{
                boatList = [select BoatType__c, Contact__c, Description__c, Geolocation__c, Length__c, Picture__c, Price__c, Year_Built__c from Boat__c];
            }
            catch(Exception ex){

                return null;
            }
        }
        System.debug('****'+boatList);
        return boatList;         
    }
}
```

BoatSearchResultcomponent.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="BoatSearchResults" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="boatTypeId" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="boats" type="Boat__c[]"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
```

BoatSearchResultComponentController.js

```
    ({
        doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        helper.onSearch(component, event, helper);                
    },
   })
```

BoatSearchResultComponentHelper.js

```
  ({
        onSearch : function(component, event, helper) {

    var action = component.get("c.getBoats");

    action.setParams({
            boatTypeId : component.get("v.boatTypeId"),
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response){

        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('Is it error'+response.getState());
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {

            var resArr = response.getReturnValue(); 
            console.log('*****'+resArr);
            component.set("v.boats", resArr);                
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);       
}
})
```

The response.getState() is continuously coming up as error. What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it is because of the geo-location field. I have currently queried the individual components of the geo-location field separately. It is not throwing an error in js anymore.

select BoatType__c, Contact__c, Description__c, Geolocation__Latitude__s, Geolocation__Longitude__s,  Length__c, Picture__c, Price__c, Year_Built__c from Boat__c

Don't know if there will be an issue when I have to actually use the geo-location field for any of the later challenges.

Answer (score 1):

`response.getState()` returns an ERROR if the server-side action fails to execute. Your code worked for me when I replaced `Boat__c` with a custom object of my own and just the Id and Name fields selected. Have you checked the debug logs? FYI - I noticed that `catch` statement in `else` condition is missing a debug statement.

Does `select BoatType__c, Contact__c, Description__c, Geolocation__c, Length__c, Picture__c, Price__c, Year_Built__c from Boat__c where BoatType__c = '<boatTypeIdHere>'` work for you in Query Editor in Developer Console?

Comment: Yes, the results are populating in the developer console, But the response request in js in coming as error. @Kal

Comment: How about debug logs?

Comment: I checked debug logs too. All the records are coming up in the query, with no issue. But still throwing a server-side error in js controller.

Comment: That is highly unlikely. Are you sure you see the output of System.debug('****'+boatList); in debug logs? Do you see a value for boatList there?

Comment: Yes I see a value for boatList, I am getting the following records 05:29:37.0 (4955569)|USER_DEBUG|[26]|DEBUG|****(Boat__c:{BoatType__c=a0K6F00000gSUUEUA4, Contact__c=0036F00002Y1aQbQAJ, Geolocation__c=API location: [38.875052 -77.049531], Length__c=20, Picture__c=/resource/Sailboats/sailboat1.png, Price__c=100000, Year_Built__c=2015, Id=a0L6F00001FE78wUAD}, Boat__c:{BoatType__c=a0K6F00000gSUUEUA4, Contact__c=0036F00002Y1aQcQAJ, Geolocation__c=API location: [39.282735 -76.6170849], Length__c=30, Picture__c=/resource/Sailboats/sailboat2.png, Price__c=500000, Year_Built__c=2013, ...... @Kal

Comment: I can't think of anything else other than having you try clearing your browser cache and/or restarting it completely.

Answer (score -1):

In getboats apex method, change `List<Boat__c> boatList= null`; 
to `List<Boat__c> boatList= new List<Boat__c> ();`

Comment: It is still coming up as an error.

Comment: List<Boat__c> boatList= null; is valid in this context because the apex method is directly assigning the result of a SOQL querying Boat__c to boatList.